# Get json from a function through JavaScript issue

Tags: javascript, php, json

I have this JavaScript code which is supposed to get values from the database in a JSON format. I use it to put multiple tags into a input field. I cannot get it to work, apparently there is a problem with the way the function is called and no data is retrieved.

When I debug it in the browser, it doesn't get past the point of:

```
return $.get('functions.php', { query: query, filter:"users" },
```

The JavaScript code:

```
source: function (query, process) {
            return $.get('functions.php', { query: query, filter:"users" }, function (data) {
              data = $.parseJSON(data);
              return process(data);
            });
          },
```

functions.php

```
switch($_GET['filter']) {
   case 'users':
       echo get_users_list();
       break;
   default:
       return;
}
function get_users_list() {
  global $db; 
  $sql = "SELECT name FROM dba.employee WHERE name LIKE '%".$_GET['query']."%'"; 
  $stmt = $db->prepare( $sql );
  $stmt->execute();
  $json = [];
  while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    $json[] = utf8_encode($row['name']);
  }
  return json_encode($json);
}
```

Comment: Hi Dany, Good job on using PDO there, I do need to say though that it makes no sense since you will still be vulnerable to SQL Injection. Please read this article on how to properly do this: http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php

Comment: Your js example is a bit slim. Also "*it doesnt get past the point of...*" ... what does that mean? If its got an error, let us know what that error is. Also, are you certain jquery is loaded up before your object is used?

Comment: @IncredibleHat I am quite new to debugging in the browser, but i get: HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error. I am able to retrieve the data from the query if i don't use a function, but just a php file instead, that's why I think it's the way I am calling the function.

Comment: Ah, the problem is your PHP then, if its 500. Need to debug your PHP, turn on full error reporting, check your server logs too.

Comment: @IncredibleHat thanks, now I do get a message: Undefined index: filter in the functions.php file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a few typos in the code, that's why I wasn't able to retrieve the desired information.